# Cómo corregir este error en código de Python: "list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente pseudocódigo y lo implementé de esta manera en Python. No sé si está del todo bien, me podrían ayudar a verificarlo por favor? MMe sale el siguiente error: `list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

El pseudocódigo es el siguiente:

> T es la matriz de tarifas, origen y destino los embarcaderos del que
>   se parte y al que se llega respectivamente, y C la matriz en la que
>   almacenaremos los resultados de los costes. La función
>   MenorDeLosCandidatos devuelve el menor coste entre dos puntos,
>   utilizando como base la recurrencia anteriormente expuesta.

```
   FUNC Embarcaderos ( ↓ origen, destino, n: NATURAL, ↓ T: MATRIZ DE NATURALES): NATURAL
   Variables
       C: MATRIZ DE NATURALES
       i, j: NATURAL
   Inicio
       PARA i = 1 HASTA n HACER
           C[i][i] := 0
       FIN PARA
       PARA i = 1 HASTA n HACER
           PARA j = 1 HASTA n HACER
               C[i][j] := menorDeLosCandidatos(i, j, n, T, C)
           FIN PARA
       FIN PARA
       devolver C[n] [n]
   Fin

   FUNC menorDeLosCandidatos ( ↓ origen, destino, n: NATURAL, ↓ T, C: MATRIZ DE NATURALES): NATURAL
   Variables
       temp: NATURAL
   Inicio
       temp := MAX_NATURAL
       PARA i = origen+1 HASTA n HACER
           temp := min(temp, T[origen][i] + C[i][destino])
       FIN PARA
       devolver temp
   Fin
```

Y ASÍ ES COMO LO IMPLEMENTE EN PYTHON, ME PODRÍAN COLABORAR POR FAVOR PARA SABER SI ESTA BIEN

```
def Embarcaderos ( origen, destino, n, T):
    C = []
    i=1
    j=1
    for i in n:
        C[i][i]=0
    for i in n:
        for j in n:
            C[i][j] = menorDeLosCandidatos(i, j, n, T, C)
    return C[n][n]       

def menorDeLosCandidatos (origen, destino, n, T, C):
       temp = max
       for i in [origen+1,n]:
           temp = min(temp,T[origen][i] + C[i][destino])

       return temp

T= [[10,40,100][0,20,80],[0,0,5]] 
Embarcaderos(1,4,4, T)
```

Comment: En qué linea te sale el error exactamente?

Comment: Cuando le declaro la matriz T= [[10,40,100][0,20,80],[0,0,5]], por otro será que si implemente bien el pseudocódigo?

Comment: Siempre se agradecerá el que no uses mayúsculas sostenidas, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta una coma en el primer elemento en `T= [[10,40,100][0,20,80],[0,0,5]]`, debería quedar como `T= [[10,40,100],[0,20,80],[0,0,5]]`

Comment: Ahora me sale el siguiente error en esta línea for i in n:                                                         me sale 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: porque estas usando `n` como objeto iteradle cuando `n` vale 4

Comment: Y como lo debería poner?